# Type 'SVGPathSeg' is not assignable to type 'EnterElement'. Property 'ownerDocument' is missing in type 'SVGPathSeg'

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, angular5

I'm trying to reproduce this [example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550) using [d3-ng2-service](https://github.com/tomwanzek/d3-ng2-service) service on Angular 5.

Component:

ngOnInit code:

```
let d3 = this.d3;
let d3ParentElement: Selection<HTMLElement, any, null, undefined>;
let d3Svg: Selection<SVGSVGElement, any, null, undefined>;
let d3G: Selection<SVGGElement, any, null, undefined>;
let width: number;
let height: number;

if (this.parentNativeElement !== null) {

    d3ParentElement = d3.select(this.parentNativeElement);
    d3Svg = this.d3Svg = d3ParentElement.select<SVGSVGElement>('svg');

    width = +d3Svg.attr('width');
    height = +d3Svg.attr('height');

    d3G = d3Svg.append<SVGGElement>("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2 + 40) + "," + (height / 2 + 90) + ")");

    let stratify = d3.stratify()
        .parentId(function (d) {
            return d["id"].substring(0, d["id"].lastIndexOf("."));
        });

    let tree = d3.tree()
        .size([2 * Math.PI, 500])
        .separation(function (a, b) {
            return (a["parent"] == b["parent"] ? 1 : 2) / a["depth"];
        });

    //let data = this.gruppi;
    let data = [
        {id: "flare"},
        {id: "flare.analytics"},
        {id: "flare.analytics.cluster"},
        {id: "flare.analytics.cluster.AgglomerativeCluster"},
        {id: "flare.analytics.cluster.CommunityStructure"},
        {id: "flare.analytics.cluster.HierarchicalCluster"},
        {id: "flare.analytics.cluster.MergeEdge"},
        {id: "flare.analytics.graph"},
        {id: "flare.analytics.graph.BetweennessCentrality"},
        {id: "flare.analytics.graph.LinkDistance"},
        {id: "flare.analytics.graph.MaxFlowMinCut"},
        {id: "flare.analytics.graph.ShortestPaths"},
        {id: "flare.analytics.graph.SpanningTree"},
        {id: "flare.analytics.optimization"},
        {id: "flare.analytics.optimization.AspectRatioBanker"},
        {id: "flare.animate"},
        {id: "flare.animate.Easing"},
        {id: "flare.animate.FunctionSequence"},
        {id: "flare.animate.interpolate"},
        {id: "flare.animate.interpolate.ArrayInterpolator"},
        {id: "flare.animate.interpolate.ColorInterpolator"},
        {id: "flare.animate.interpolate.DateInterpolator"},
        {id: "flare.animate.interpolate.Interpolator"},
        {id: "flare.animate.interpolate.MatrixInterpolator"},
        {id: "flare.animate.interpolate.NumberInterpolator"},
        {id: "flare.animate.interpolate.ObjectInterpolator"},
        {id: "flare.animate.interpolate.PointInterpolator"},
        {id: "flare.animate.interpolate.RectangleInterpolator"},
        {id: "flare.animate.ISchedulable"},
        {id: "flare.animate.Parallel"},
        {id: "flare.animate.Pause"},
        {id: "flare.animate.Scheduler"},
        {id: "flare.animate.Sequence"},
        {id: "flare.animate.Transition"},
        {id: "flare.animate.Transitioner"},
        {id: "flare.animate.TransitionEvent"},
        {id: "flare.animate.Tween"},
        {id: "flare.data"},
        {id: "flare.data.converters"},
        {id: "flare.data.converters.Converters"},
        {id: "flare.data.converters.DelimitedTextConverter"},
        {id: "flare.data.converters.GraphMLConverter"},
        {id: "flare.data.converters.IDataConverter"},
        {id: "flare.data.converters.JSONConverter"},
        {id: "flare.data.DataField"},
        {id: "flare.data.DataSchema"},
        {id: "flare.data.DataSet"},
        {id: "flare.data.DataSource"},
        {id: "flare.data.DataTable"},
        {id: "flare.data.DataUtil"},
        {id: "flare.display"},
        {id: "flare.display.DirtySprite"},
        {id: "flare.display.LineSprite"},
        {id: "flare.display.RectSprite"},
        {id: "flare.display.TextSprite"},
        {id: "flare.flex"},
        {id: "flare.flex.FlareVis"},
        {id: "flare.physics"},
        {id: "flare.physics.DragForce"},
        {id: "flare.physics.GravityForce"},
        {id: "flare.physics.IForce"},
        {id: "flare.physics.NBodyForce"},
        {id: "flare.physics.Particle"},
        {id: "flare.physics.Simulation"},
        {id: "flare.physics.Spring"},
        {id: "flare.physics.SpringForce"},
        {id: "flare.query"},
        {id: "flare.query.AggregateExpression"},
        {id: "flare.query.And"},
        {id: "flare.query.Arithmetic"},
        {id: "flare.query.Average"},
        {id: "flare.query.BinaryExpression"},
        {id: "flare.query.Comparison"},
        {id: "flare.query.CompositeExpression"},
        {id: "flare.query.Count"},
        {id: "flare.query.DateUtil"},
        {id: "flare.query.Distinct"},
        {id: "flare.query.Expression"},
        {id: "flare.query.ExpressionIterator"},
        {id: "flare.query.Fn"},
        {id: "flare.query.If"},
        {id: "flare.query.IsA"}
    ];

    let root = tree(stratify(data));

    let radial = d3.linkRadial()
        .angle(function(d){ return d["x"];})
        .radius(function(d){ return d["y"];});

    let link = d3G.selectAll<SVGElement, any>(".link")
        .data(root.links())
        .enter()
        .append<SVGPathSeg>("path")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d",radial);

    let radialPoint = function(x, y) {
        return [(y = +y) * Math.cos(x -= Math.PI / 2), y * Math.sin(x)];
    };

    let node = d3G.selectAll<SVGElement, any>(".node")
        .data(root.descendants())
        .enter()
        .append<SVGGElement>("g")
        .attr("class", function (d) {
            return "node" + (d["children"] ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf");
        })
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + radialPoint(d["x"], d["y"]) + ")";
        });

    node.append<SVGCircleElement>("circle")
        .attr("r", 2.5);

    node.append<SVGTextElement>("text")
        .attr("dy", "0.31em")
        .attr("x", function (d) {
            return d["x"] < Math.PI === !d["children"] ? 6 : -6;
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", function (d) {
            return d["x"] < Math.PI === !d["children"] ? "start" : "end";
        })
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "rotate(" + (d["x"] < Math.PI ? d["x"] - Math.PI / 2 : d["x"] + Math.PI / 2) * 180 / Math.PI + ")";
        })
        .text(function (d) {
            return d["id"].substring(d["id"].lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        });
    // Do more D3 things
}
```

This works and i get a pretty decent result:
[Angular component output](https://ibb.co/g3uNh7)

But i keep getting an error output by angular telling:

```
ERROR in src/app/grafo/grafo.component.ts(262,25): error TS2344: Type 'SVGPathSeg' does not satisfy the constraint 'BaseType'.
  Type 'SVGPathSeg' is not assignable to type 'EnterElement'.
    Property 'ownerDocument' is missing in type 'SVGPathSeg'.
```

[PhpStorm hint](https://ibb.co/ix6Dpn)

That refer to this part of code:

```
let link = d3G.selectAll<SVGElement, any>(".link")
                .data(root.links())
                .enter()
                .append<SVGPathSeg>("path")
                .attr("class", "link")
                .attr("d",radial);
```

I'm struggling to find a fix for that and really don't know if is a framework issue or an error of mine somewhere.

As suggested by tomwanzek on this [issue](https://github.com/tomwanzek/d3-ng2-service/issues/114#issuecomment-377596157) i've tried to replace `SVGPathSeg` with `SVGPathElement` but this will trigger an error two lines below at `.attr("d",radial)`:

```
let link = d3G.selectAll<SVGElement, any>(".link")
                .data(root.links())
                .enter()
                .append<SVGPathSeg>("path")
                .attr("class", "link")
                .attr("d",radial);
```

I was using `SVGPathSeg` before because it accepted the `.attr("d", radial)`.

https://ibb.co/g5CN0S

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'LinkRadial<any, DefaultLinkObject, [number,number]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValueFn<SVGPathElement, HierarchyPointLink<{}>, string | number | boolean>'.
```

I've missed some type somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to ensure the different parts in your code play nicely together, there is a need to utilize some of the generics offered on the generators (stratification, tree) and the link path generator.

For ease of reference, assume you define:

```
interface Datum {
  id: string;
}
```

as your `data` are of type `Datum[]`

Then, the following changes will ensure compatible types are used, preventing the errors described above.

```
// ...    
const stratify = d3.stratify<Datum>()
// ...
const tree = d3.tree<Datum>()
// ...
const radial = d3.linkRadial<HierarchyPointLink<Datum>, HierarchyPointNode<Datum>>()
```

Note that `HierarchyPointLink<Datum>` and `HierarchyPointNode<Datum>` are the link and node type as created by the tree layout generator, when used on underlying data of type `Datum`.

Additionally, of course, the bound DOM element type is `SVGPathElement`, i.e.

```
let link = d3G.selectAll<SVGElement, any>(".link")
    .data(root.links())
    .enter()
    .append<SVGPathElement>("path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", radial);
```